# Set up git submodule without creating commit

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a parent project with the following `.gitmodules` file

```
[submodule "src/redux"]
    path = src/redux
    url = git@github.com:username/sub-package.git
    branch = master
```

Here are the steps I'm using to clone the parent project to ensure I have the submodule set up.

```
git clone git@github.com:username/parent-project.git
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

After that, I have the contents of the submodule in the place in the parent project. However, the HEAD is detached in the submodule. First indication that I'm not doing something right. I expect this to be on the master branch since the parent project's `.gitmodules` file points to the master branch.

[image]

I then checked out master and set up the submodule's master branch to track the remote master branch.

```
git checkout master
git branch -u origin/master master
```

When i back out to the parent project and run git status i have an uncommitted change in the submodule.

[image]

I feel like I shouldn't have that change when I'm just setting it all up initially. If I did, all developers that cloned the project would also have their own unique initial commit when setting up their local environment. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git submodule modified files status](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006494/git-submodule-modified-files-status)

Comment: @smarber that does answer some questions but i still don't understand what good the `branch = master` line in the `.gitsubmodules` is good for

Answer (score 1):

Submodules are a bit tricky to work with; if you have them, you need to make sure every dev on your team understands the Git model *and* how it handles submodules.

When you add a submodule to a repo, the contents of the submodule never get added to the repo itself; the *only* thing the parent repo ever records about a submodule is the commit hash it corresponds to. You can see this if you run `git diff -- src/redux`.

What this means is that when you `git submodule init`, you're updating the working tree of the submodule to reflect the hash stored in the index; from `git-submodule(1)`:

```
   init
       Initialize the submodules recorded in the index (which were added
       and committed elsewhere) by copying submodule names and urls from
       .gitmodules to .git/config. Optional <path> arguments limit which
       submodules will be initialized. It will also copy the value of
       submodule.$name.update into .git/config. The key used in
       .git/config is submodule.$name.url. This command does not alter
       existing information in .git/config. You can then customize the
       submodule clone URLs in .git/config for your local setup and
       proceed to git submodule update; you can also just use git
       submodule update --init without the explicit init step if you do
       not intend to customize any submodule locations.
```

`.gitmodules` stores additional information about the submodule configuration, and specifically `submodule.src/redux.branch` is used when you *update* the submodule, i.e. point it at a more recent commit; also from `git-submodule(1)`:

```
   --remote
       This option is only valid for the update command. Instead of using
       the superproject’s recorded SHA-1 to update the submodule, use the
       status of the submodule’s remote-tracking branch. The remote used
       is branch’s remote (branch.<name>.remote), defaulting to origin.
       The remote branch used defaults to master, but the branch name may
       be overridden by setting the submodule.<name>.branch option in
       either .gitmodules or .git/config (with .git/config taking
       precedence).
```

Comment: what happens if within the submodule, you create and switch to a feature branch then back out of the submodule and do a `git submodule update` and the `.gitmodules` file specifices `branch = master`? does that pull in the masters commits to your feature branch?

Comment: Again, from `git-submodule(1)`: "`update`: Update the registered submodules to match what the superproject expects by cloning missing submodules and updating the working tree of the submodules. The "updating" can be done in several ways depending on command line options and the value of submodule.<name>.update configuration variable."